# How can I search for a state based on a user's full-name input, when I'm only storing the state code?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query in eloquent.

```
$profiles = Profile::where('full_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('area_description','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('state','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->paginate(10);
```

Which searches just fine based on the state code if you provide something like CA, OH, NJ, etc...

But it needs to this query needs to be able to receive the full state name as input such as California, Ohio, New Jersey, etc...

I am not storing the full state name in the database, however. Is there any way I could hardcode a crosswalk table in the application? I'd really prefer not to have to make database structure changes at this point in the project.

Comment: Do you have state code and name array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have an array of state code and state name:

```
$data = [
  'AL' => 'Alabama',
  'AK' => 'Alaska',
  'AZ' => 'Arizona',
  'CA' => 'California',
  'CO' => 'Colorado'
];
```

Input by user

```
$query = 'ala';
```

So user search 'ala' it should get two states.
first find all state code related to search:

```
$result = array_filter($data, function ($item) use ($query) {
    if (stripos($item, $query) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

$state_codes =array_keys($result);
```

`$state_codes` have all state code related to search and now you can use in query:

```
$profiles = Profile::where('full_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
->orWhere('area_description','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
->orWhereIn('state',$state_codes)
->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the state full name in your application config if you want, for an example, I store the full name in `state.php` in the config folder like this :

```
return [
    'CA' => 'California,
]
```

then I can search the full name by the key code like this :

```
$stateFullname = config('state');

$stateFullname[$profile->state];
```

Read more at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)